# Why my random projection gives very low quality?

Tags: python, machine-learning, probability, dimensionality-reduction

Why my random projection gives very low quality?

```
import numpy as np

n = 10
p = 9999
s = 99
A = np.random.rand(n,p)*10
print(np.shape(A))
B = np.random.normal(size=(p,s))/np.sqrt(s)
print(np.shape(B))
C = np.dot(A,B)
print(np.shape(C))
print(np.linalg.norm(A[1,:]-A[2,:]))
print(np.linalg.norm(C[1,:]-C[2,:]))
print(np.linalg.norm(A[1,:]-A[3,:]))
print(np.linalg.norm(C[1,:]-C[3,:]))
```

output

```
(10, 9999)
(9999, 99)
(10, 99)
406.963872131
397.535303822
404.303968464
399.035882726
```

Relative distances are not enough to distinguish. Not being preserved exactly as well.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? `B` is only approximately an isometry, the observed differences are not that large. As this is not a coding problem, the question would be better asked on the mathematics, statistics or scientific computing portals of the stackexchange.com network.

Comment: It is not that bad, If you consider the ratios of the approximate distances are 406/397 ~= 1.02 and 404/399 ~=  1.012 . So the pairwise distances are relatively preserved as expected by the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Lindenstrauss_lemma . Note the error term in the lemma is O(1/eps^2), so if you need more digits of precision, you need more dimensions.